# How to import models from other sibling app in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django-models

i create a project in django 
in this project i am use the no. of app like

home ,payment

i am create some models in home/model.py file 
and i want to use this model as a ForeignKey in payment/model.py file but i can't access and implode that file on this location  i am using no. of method but it's give me some error.

show please help me how to access this file on this location

Thank You

[image]

Comment: Just import it as `from home.models import ...`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can import your `models` module from `CoupoonCode` library

```
from home.models import CoupoonCode
```